# Want to update column to colum value in Magento2 update query

Tags: magento2

Hello all I want to write a query magento 2 update query way where I can update 1 column value to another column value as below

update table_name set column1 = column2 where id =1;

Please help

Comment: I guess your answer is here [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Comment: I know from mysql , I want to write using ->update( function.